Help Needed with Compact Circuit Design for Pulse-Triggered Switch-Off Sequence
I am currently working on a small electronics project for my swimming club and could use some advice. Forgive me if this is basic, I'm really new to electronics.
The project requires a compact circuit with the following specifications:

Outputs high (3.3V) on power-up
Waits for a clock pulse
Upon receiving the pulse, switches off (and outputs low) after a defined delay (probably using a rc circuit)
Remains off until power is cycled, regardless of additional pulses

I have attempted to simulate this circuit using D flip-flops paired with an NPN transistor and SR latches, simulating in LTspice, but haven't had any luck so far. I’m operating on a very high density pcb so using a microcontroller (or 555 timer) is not an option.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
For clarification:

By "output goes low," I mean that the Vout line of this circuit switches from a logic high state to a low state. This Vout line is connected to the data input of a shift register.

Width range of input pulse: The pulse is a 1Hz square wave with a pulse width of 500ms.

Time range of output delay: This delay can be very small. I am using a shift register to take the input from this circuit, so I don't want the circuit outputting low before the shift register registers it.



1 - When you say the output goes low, do you mean it pulls a downstream input low, or that it goes open-circuit?  2 - Width range of input pulse?  3 - Time range of output delay?  Please update your question with these details.

You actually need two R-C circuits, one to assure that the flipflop powers up in the correct state, and one to create the output delay.  The whole thing can be done with two NAND gates (1/2 of a quad NAND package) or one flipflop (one-half of a dual ff package), or two transistors (but with a less "snappy" output pulse squareness).  Or two 555's but that's no fun.

Based on the updated information -
Because of the requirement to ignore subsequent input pulses, you still need a latch circuit of some kind.  Also, the shift register input probably would not like a slow edge.  1/2 of a dual D flipflop will do this, but I like to do things with gates.
Here is a first-pass at a schematic using a D flipflop.

R1-C1 form a power-on-reset for the flipflop.  This assures that the circuit powers up with the Q output low and the Q- output high.
R2-C2 form the input clock delay.  Adjust to taste.
C3 is the power supply decoupling for U1.  R3 provides a discharge path for C1 when power is removed from the circuit.  This assures that the power-on-reset will happen even if power is bounced quickly.
But wait . . .
Here is the same function done with NAND gates.  All of the R and C functions are the same.  The 4th gate is unused.
UPDATE:  There might be a power-on timing issue in this schematic.  The C2 power-on state conflicts with C1, and this puts a limit on the delay time range.  Use the D ff circuit instead.

UPDATE:
Here is an updated version of circuit #2.  It uses the spare ff to improve consistency.  It provides a stable, high input impedance to whatever is supplying the clock pulse, and drives the R2-C2 delay network with a stable, low impedance.  It also removes any timing conflict between the C1 and C2 circuits.  R4 helps to reset C2 more quickly.


Thank you so much for your help! I will try this out and see how it goes.

Schematics updated with minor tweaks.

Hi, thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate the effort you put into this. Again, thank you.

I ran into a similar problem a few weeks ago (with different logic), what I found is a micro is a way to go because you can get very small micros. You do have the challenge of programming them but given the right micro you can pre-program them before reflow. We ended up saving money on the BOM and space on the PCB.

I'm not sure if that solution will work for my application. I'm planning to get the board fabricated through JLCPCB, and I'm working with 001005 size components. Do you have any recommendations on how to start designing a circuit like this?

I do but I don't have time right now to properly come up with a circuit

STM32C011D6 is available in WLCSP12 - 1.7x1.42mm package. Programming lines can be on a part of the PCB that you break off after programming

ATTINY20-UUR in 12-WLCSP (1.56mmx1.4mm) is even in stock at Digikey.

Spike is correct in that nothing will be smaller or cheaper (in volume) than a uC.  The entire circuit is one 6-pin chip and one decoupling cap.  That's it - no timing components, and the power-on-reset is built into the uC.  You need one GPIO pin for the input, another one for the output, and (of course) c.o.d.e.  At Digi-Key, it looks like the winner is the ATTINY10-TSHR at 44 cents for 1.

One of solution is below:
A monostable gets triggered with input pulse.
After delay of monostable generate a trigger pulse setting the Latch low.


Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. I'll make this and see how it goes.

A problem here (and with my NAND circuit) is that if power is applied while the input signal is high, the mmv triggers immediately rather than waiting for the next true positive edge.  The solution for this circuit is to differentiate the input waveform, but that adds more parts and space to the design.
